# objects are not initialized in another .js file?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

**[SOLVED - see at the end please]**

[EDITED]

I have the following source:

index.js:

```
functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin = require('firebase-admin');

globals = require('./globals');
.....
admin.initializeApp();

exports.gateway = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   .....
   return globals.dumpItemName(1);
});

exports.POST_gateway = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   .....
   return globals.dumpItemName(1);
});    


globals.dumpItemName(1);
```

globals.js:

```
....
ITEM_NAMES = new Map()
   .set(1, 'item1')
   .set(2, 'item2');
....
getMapValue = function(map, key) {
   let value = map.get(key);
   if (value === undefined) {
       throw new Error('Missing value for key ' + key);
   }
   return value;
}
....
dumpItemName = function(key) {
    console.log(getMapValue(ITEM_NAMES, key));
}

exports.dumpItemName = dumpItemName;
```

**I'm facing the following problem:**

1. If I run/debug it locally by F5 it executes fine and dumps the expected value.
2. If I try to deploy it by firebase deploy --only functions
   and then call via postman an https.onRequest(...) or https.onCall(....) function which tries to do the same:

   globals.dumpItemName(1);

it fails with 'Missing value for key 1'

So I guess when I run it locally with F5 it executes index.js like a program and loads required modules and also run the code in them - so the Map in globals.js is initialized.

But when I deploy it via firebase deploy --functions only it does not execute the code.

**So what should I do in order to have Map initialized after deploy ?**

---

**[SOLVED - THE REASON FOR THE "PROBLEM"]**

Extremely dummy of my side.

Obviously for some of the local tests
(I have by now 10 end-to-end test scenario functions) I've put in index.js the following piece of code:

```
  //!!! JUST FOR TEST - REMOVE IT !!!
  ITEM_NAMES = new Map()
    .set(globals.ITEM_TEST, 'test');
  //!!! JUST FOR TEST - REMOVE IT !!!
```

so this map was redeclared with just one value in it. and the value of globals.ITEM_TEST is 200.
and it was used in one temporary test scenario function.

And just bad coincidences:

1. obviously I was too tired and forgot about it.
2. my other local tests were commented and that's why the local run was successful - in this temporary scenario, only this value was used.
3. I've decided to deploy in this exact moment. And none of the values I used in my onCall() or onRequest() functions used globals.ITEM_TEST  (in real and in dummy both)

So it is...
Sorry for bothering. There is no problem in fact.

Comment: You haven't shown any code that actually creates an HTTP function or a callable function.  You need to use the functions SDK declare your function.  Where is that code?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: I've edited the code.


I have the same problem with this simple dummy code as with my real code. Initially I thought the problem was in my real code and I've put that very simple dummy code just dumping the itemname but the problem is the same: the Map() is not initialized as it is in local run with F5 with VSCode.

Comment: You should check your functions with `firebase serve --only functions`

Comment: Yes, the same result with firebase serve --only functions and test via Postman.

Obviously the map is not initialized in globals.js as it is if I just use F5 to simply test as a normal program.

Comment: Maybe I should put the initialization in some function and I to this function from index.js.   (Map is local for globals.js because it's used only by getMapValue() function)

Comment: I'm a newbie in .js so I don't know is there any code which is executed after deploy?   For example code placed directly in index.js outside any functions etc.   Does require(....) just loads the module or executes the code in module body ?   Obviously during local run/debug in VSCode the code is executed. But what about the deploy ?

Comment: I've found the reason. extremely dummy of my side.  I've added the explanation at the end of the question because of the better formatting.